# Race condition in python telegram bot library

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I'm using [python-telegram-bot library](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) (PTB) to build my own bot.
Let assume for example, there is implemented some logic to process user message and
echo it back to user.
Also it's required to run it concurrently for an arbitrary amounts of users.
This is possible in PTB, for example, passing `block = False` to handler function [concurrency in PTB](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Concurrency#handlerblock).

I would like to know is the following code snippet is vulnerable for the race condition case.

```
import asyncio

from telegram.ext import (ApplicationBuilder,AIORateLimiter, CommandHandler)

BOT_TOKEN = "YOUR_BOT_TOKEN"

async def echo(update, context):
    try:
        chat_id = update.message.chat_id
        message = ' '.join(context.args)
        await application.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

application = ApplicationBuilder().token(BOT_TOKEN).rate_limiter(AIORateLimiter()).build()
application.add_handler(CommandHandler('echo', echo, block=False))
application.run_polling()
```